# How to load dynamic label and data from controller in chart?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, chart.js

I'm using List to load radar chart  from controller.
How can i load dynamic labels and data for that chart from controller.

```
        List<MyModel> modelIist = new List<MyModel>();   
        MyModel model = new MyModel();
        model.Data = 1;
        model.Label = "First";
        modelIist.Add(model);
        model = new MyModel();
        model.Data = 2;
        model.Label = "Second";
        modelIist.Add(model);
        model = new MyModel();
        model.Data = 3;
        model.Label = "Third ";
        modelIist.Add(model); 
        ViewBag.radarDesc = modelIist;
```

I'm loading data above  from above list.

```js
   <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var ctx = $("#chart-line");
            var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'radar',
                data: {
                        labels: [],  //want to load from the list
                                /*},*/
            
                    datasets: [{
                    data: [],//want to load from the list
                        label: "MyData",
                        borderColor: "#458af7",
                        backgroundColor: '#458af7',
                        fill: true
                    }]
                },
                options: {
                    title: {
                        display: true,
                        text: '(Max points - 300)'
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.1.4/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="chart-line" width="299" height="200" class="chartjs-render-monitor" style="display: block; width: 299px; height: 200px;"></canvas>
```

How can load label: [], data:[] from mvc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

Install `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson` NuGet Package and then serialize the `ViewBag.radarDesc` into a valid JavaScript array：

```
ViewBag.radarDesc = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(modelIist);
```

Then take out the `Label` and `Data` in the Page and fill it to the appropriate position:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var Label = [];
        var Data = [];
        var radarDesc = @Html.Raw(@ViewBag.radarDesc);
        $.each(radarDesc, function (index, value) {
            Label.push(value.Label);
            Data.push(value.Data);
        });

        var ctx = $("#chart-line");
        var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'radar',
            data: {
                labels: Label,  //want to load from the list
                /*},*/

                datasets: [{
                    data: Data,//want to load from the list
                    label: "MyData",
                    borderColor: "#458af7",
                    backgroundColor: '#458af7',
                    fill: true
                }]
            },
            options: {
                title: {
                    display: true,
                    text: '(Max points - 300)'
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

Test Result:

[image]